# Left join problems in oracle

Tags: oracle, left-join

I hope anyone can help me :) My problem is when i run my code i am seeing this error " SQL command not properly ended" and "example" is red.
Thank you for your interested

```
(select  mat.oid matoid
  from lsn.material mat,
       lsn.plan_def def,
       lsn.unit meu
 where     math.plan_def_oid = def.oid
       and math.unit_oid = meu.oid
       )example left  join lsn.plan_det det on  det.def_oid = example .matoid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just join all four tables together in one go:

```
select math.oid matoid
from lsn.material mat
inner join lsn.plan_def def
    on math.plan_def_oid = def.oid
inner join lsn.unit meu
    on math.unit_oid = meu.oid
left join lsn.plan_det det
    on plan_def_oid = math.oid
```

Changes I made here include converting your implicit joins to explicit inner joins.  As a general rule, you should avoid putting commas into the `from` clause.  Also I moved your original incomplete subquery out to the main query.

Comment: @Henry I don't know `linq` unfortunately, but if you open a new question, referencing this one, I'm sure you'll get help quickly :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, it looks like there is a reference to a RESULTS table that is missing

Comment: I also didn't know what to make of that.  But the column referenced with `result` is the same as the alias in the select, so I just used that.

Comment: you right. i edit "result" to "example" but i forgot to change it. thank u i correct it.